# ROS Answers SE migration: int callback

Tags: ros, callback, callbacks, topics, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to have a callback function other than type void? If yes, how would you handle a situation where you call ros::spinOnce() and say you are subscribing to two different topics each with their own callback function... how would you store the variable that one of the callback functions returned?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39921/int-callback/) by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 600 on 2012-07-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would say: No.

For the reason that you basically explained yourself: What would one do with the return value?, What is the meaning of that?

PS: Maybe, your intended usage of ros::spinOnce is based on a misconception. ros::spinOnce will not call one callback, but all available callbacks at the time. For more information, see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-26**:
Possibly a boolean return? That could be useful in some scenario.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-27**:
But who would use that? Callbacks come from spin, so what should happen in spin if a callback returns false? Things like error handling in client code should not go through spin, but be handled directly by the callback (IMO). Figuring out what callback caused a false return would also be messy.